# backbone.js filter collection using substring

Tags: javascript, xcode, backbone.js, underscore.js

The following problem is driving me crazy.

```
_.each(collection, function( account, key ){

    var totalPhy = that.physicianCollection.where({ 'Hospital_Id__c' : account.Id }).length;
    account.physicians = { 'total' : totalPhy };
});
```

It is working when `Hospital_Id__c` same as account.Id. But my account Id is a sub string of the `hospital_Id__c`. How do I search and get the count? I tried index of and search methods. Pls suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that account.Id is a substring of Hospital_Id__c and not vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

`_.where` is a simple use case of `_.filter` to match exact properties. In your case you will need to actually use `_.filter` and write the logic yourself. I'm not sure what the account id / hospital id look like, but the code will probably look something like :

```
var totalPhy = that.physicianCollection.filter(function(phys, index, collection){
    //phys is your model
    return phys.get('Hospital_Id__c').indexOf(account.Id) != -1; 
    //(or however the ids are set, your logic here)
}).length;
account.physicians = { 'total' : totalPhy };
```

http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Comment: For some reasons indexOf is not working in my current code. It is backbone hybrid iPad app. Any suggestions?